# Facebook share Fitness - not visible on friends wall, moods

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good day to all,

- I'm developing Android app, that share recorded track on facebook over [OpenGraphStories - Action, fitness.*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/fitness) .
- whole system works correctly - creating "course" object, attaching ID of new course to "action" and in the end, Story is visible on my own timeline together with map preview and bottom parameters.

Here comes two questions. I'm also testing application "Runtastic". Differences I'm unable to solve:

1. shared "action" from Runtastic is visible also on friends timeline, not just mine
2. Runtastic is able to include also moods (feelings), but I see no specification in API, no matter where I searched.

These parameters are used, so I see nothing what else I may do.

> request.addBodyParameter("no_feed_story", "false");
>   request.addBodyParameter("fb:explicitly_shared", "true");

Checked all possible places in FB account, but both apps has exactly same permissions as well as my Friends.

Am I missing something or has Runtastic some extra permissions?

**EDIT**: maybe useful info, I'm using HTTP requests directly, not Android Facebook SDK.

Comment: Are you action type approved? Is it approved for fb:explicitly_shared? Is your app live?

Comment: Yes it is. All three types of action (walk/bike/run) is approved as well as "Explicitly shared" permission under all three actions. There are no error messages, all is correctly visible on my own profile, just the "small" difference compare to Runtastic app.